# Custom taxonomies won't display alphabetically

Tags: wordpress

Is there anyone who knows why this is going on. Wordpress lists my custom taxonomies in the order they where inserted and not alphabetically. This is the code I'm using.

```
function get_the_term_list_inclusief( $id, $taxonomy, $before = '', $sep = '', $after = '') {
$terms = get_the_terms( $id, $taxonomy );

if ( is_wp_error( $terms ) )
    return $terms;


if ( empty( $terms ) )
    return false;

$links = array();

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $link = get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy );
    if ( is_wp_error( $link ) ) {
        return $link;
    }
    $links[] = '<a class="ajax" href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '" rel="tag">' . $term->name . '</a>';
}

/**
 * Filter the term links for a given taxonomy.
 *
 * The dynamic portion of the filter name, `$taxonomy`, refers
 * to the taxonomy slug.
 *
 * @since 2.5.0
 *
 * @param array $links An array of term links.
 */
$term_links = apply_filters( "term_links-$taxonomy", $links );

return $before . join( $sep, $term_links ) . $after;
```

}

Is there away to use this code and have the taxonomies order by title or ASC?

Thanks

Comment: A simple `sort($terms)` before your foreach loop maybe …?

Comment: Like this:

`$links = array();
    sort($terms);

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {` ?

Comment: @CBroe, that didn't work. I placed it all over the function but with no luck.

Comment: I see, `get_the_terms` does not simply return taxonomy term names, but an array of objects. So it might rather need `usort` with a little custom comparison function, that compares two objects based on their `name` property.

Comment: Yeah, and that just went straight over my head...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try if this works:

```
// ...
$links = array();

usort($terms, function($a, $b) {
  return strcmp($a->name, $b->name);
});

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
// ...
```